# Show an image from models in Django

Tags: python, django, image, templates, imagefield

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem with the images but I can't find the answer. I'm trying to display an 'ImageField' of my models to a template.

I have uploaded an image through the admin site, and when I want to display it, I can't render the image properly (it appears an icon but can't see the image).

The model I'm trying to show the image from has this statement for the ImageField:

```
figure = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img/list-icons',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               verbose_name=_("Figure"))
```

Being the 'upload_to' path the path to the static files directory where the images are stored. I'm trying to get the image in the Template with this code (I've tried several combinations):

```
{% for quiz in quiz_list %}

            <tr>
              <td>{{ quiz.title }}</td>
              <td>{{ quiz.category }}</td>
              <td><img src="{{ quiz.figure.url }}" /></td>
              <td>{{ quiz.single_attempt }}</td>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
```

The model is Quiz(ListView) and I've not changed anything from the `views.py` (just added recently the images field). Would it be required to add some statements? What kind of?

I've added a mere aproximation of `'MEDIA_ROOT'` in `settings.py`, with the path to my static images directory (same as the upload_to in the model), also I'm not sure how to define or if it's necessary to define the `'MEDIA_URL'`.

How could I display images directly from the Model (I also tried `{{quiz.figure}}` but just got the 'upload_to' path displayed), picking them from the static directory where they are located? Help would be highly appreciated, thank you. I'll answer to add required aditional info.

**EDIT 1:** the capture of what it outputs right now is just this:

[Capture of what it outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNugZ.png)

My urls.py file ends like this:

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

i think it's required to make CSS working properly as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not rendering the image properly.

You should replace

```
<td><img src="quiz.figure.url" /></td>
```

with

```
<td><img src="{{ quiz.figure.url }}" /></td>
```

**UPDATE**:
It appears that you don't have media url entry in your project urls.py. In the project urls, do this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also, Make sure you have defined appropriate settings in your settings.py

```
# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Thank you, just fixed it, but the output is still the same... Should I manage something with the 'MEDIA_ROOT' or 'MEDIA_URL' in settings.py?

Comment: what is the output? do you have media urls in your urlpatterns?

Comment: I've edited the first post, what you mean by media urls? I've just the normal url config patterns, haven't changed anything when I added the imagefield in models. Should it have a path or something in the urls.py? Thank you for the answers

Comment: Yes, to view media files from development server you need to have an entry for media urls in your project urls.py (just like you do with static files).

Answer (score 0):

Update 2024
Django 3.2.7

Make sure you add following in
setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "myapp/static")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

then use image tag

```
{% for image in images %}
<td><img src="{{image.photo.url}}"></td>
{% endfor %}
```